# Want to know how to fix a period of tenure for my redirection of any particular page through clicking a button?

Tags: java, android

Can Anybody tell me that how can I add a particular period of tenure in android studio by a same button ?

Sorry Everybody But I am a new coder and making an educational app for a organization and created all the things successfully but I am lagging only at one particular point. My app contains different courses which are paid. My dashboard is captured in the [dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKF4s.png).And On Clicking Any course [1st Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9vFI.png) will open. As you can see in this [1st Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9vFI.png) screenshot I gave a buy button in every course. And connected that buying server to razorpay and also fixed the amount for every course. But I wanted a method like when a user paid for that course an another page will view for only that user when he clicks on any course in [dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKF4s.png) after clicking any course onclick view like this[2nd Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA9S7.png) for paid users.

And not only this much, I am also searching for such a method in which the 2nd page will view for that paid user for a particular period of 1 month and then again [1st Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9vFI.png) will take place because my course period is of only 1 month.

I have also 2 situation methods for razorpay like in the below mentioned source code.

```java
@Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        builder.setTitle ("Payment ID");
        builder.setMessage (s);
        builder.show ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (),s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

    }
```

. And I am also knowing that I have to write codes in the onPaymentSuccess method but I`m not knowing the codes. Please Help Me! Anybody.......

Other Source Codes that I have:-

1. Dashboard Xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh_layout">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">


                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
                    android:id="@+id/menuicon"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"/>
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profilepic2"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dashboard"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:id="@+id/text_view"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_black"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="start">

                </TextView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/miscellaneous1"
                        android:onClick="miscelllaneous1"
                        android:src="@drawable/final1"
                        android:transitionName="miscellaneouslogo"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/history1"
                        android:onClick="history"
                        android:transitionName="history1"
                        android:src="@drawable/final3"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="gkgs"
                        android:transitionName="gkgs1"
                        android:id="@+id/gkgs1"
                        android:src="@drawable/final2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/currentaffairs1"
                        android:transitionName="currentaffairs1"
                        android:onClick="currentaffairs1"
                        android:src="@drawable/final4"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BY ASTHA ORGANIZATION LMTD."
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>




</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2. My First buying course page xml:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".History_Course">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:transitionName="history1"
            android:src="@drawable/history1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HISTORY Full Course"
            android:fontFamily="@font/muli_black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="30dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Course Duration:1 Month"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
                android:text="Course Contains : 20 Videos, weekly live\nclasses,Solving Queries during a specific time through phone calls and many more premium facilities."/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Video Topics:- Full History Videos will be given to you with most easiest tricks to remember.Videos are fully based on mostly competitive examinations and also for exams like NET, UPSC, Railways, Banking and many more like these exams.At the time of nearby exams videos will be more interactive.So if you have any type of doubt then please contact"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
                android:text="Classes Held By:- "/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dr.Vibha Singh\nDone Doctorate of Philoshophy in History."
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli_black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
                android:text="Course Price : ₹699"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_bag"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BUY NOW"
                    android:id="@+id/historybuybtn"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_black"
                    android:background="@drawable/buy_button_bg"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

3. My First buying course page java :-

```java
package com.example.asthamentor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.razorpay.Checkout;
import com.razorpay.PaymentResultListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class History_Course extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentResultListener {

    Button buybtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_history_course);
        buybtn = findViewById (R.id.historybuybtn);

        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager (this, SessionManager.SESSION_USERSESSION);
        HashMap<String, String> usersDetails = sessionManager.getusersdetailfromsession ();

        String _email = usersDetails.get (SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
        String _phoneno = usersDetails.get (SessionManager.KEY_PHONENUMBER);

        String sAmount = "69900";

        int amount = Math.round (Float.parseFloat (sAmount) );

        buybtn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Checkout checkout = new Checkout ();

                checkout.setKeyID ("Sorry its personal");

                checkout.setImage (R.drawable.razorpayicon);

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject ();
                try {
                    object.put ("name", "History Course");
                    object.put ("Descrytion","Test Payment");
                    object.put ("theme.color","#008EFF");
                    object.put ("currency", "INR");
                    object.put ("amount",amount);
                    object.put ("prefill.contact",_phoneno);
                    object.put ("prefill.email",_email);
                    checkout.open (History_Course.this,object);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        builder.setTitle ("Payment ID");
        builder.setMessage (s);
        builder.show ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (),s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

    }
}
```

Anybody please please help me! I`m in this trouble by 3 weeks ago. For that guy, I`m always grateful to him.

Comment: Please  help me anybody else i have lose my 20 days labour